# What SF&F movies are referenced in this gif?

Tags: story-identification, movie, character-identification, john-carpenter

### This adorably badass gif is the work of Truck Torrence, aka [100% Soft](http://100percentsoft.com/)

[image]

Obviously, the whole thing is a reference to John Carpenter's *They Live*, and it appears that all the references are to Carpenter films: The hamburger in snow on the sign at the bottom is a reference to *John Carpenter's The Thing* (MacReady's Flamebroiled Thingburgers).  The pizza place is also a John Carpenter reference - *Escape from New York*.  Michael Myers, another Carpenter creation, is also visible, and *Precinct 13* is yet another Carpenter film.

### What other SF&F movies are referenced in the gif?

---

**For the sake of your eyes, here are two stills:**

[image]
[image]

Comment: It's more "what John Carpenter movies are referenced" :)

Comment: ...especially since some of them aren't even SF&F.

Comment: I came here to chew bubblegum and leave a comment... and I'm all out of bubblegum

Comment: In the 1990s, there was an actual restaurant in Portland, Oregon called Escape From New York Pizza.  (Maybe it's still there.)

Answer (score 17):

Posted as community wiki. Feel free to edit accordingly.

[image]
<sub><sup>Font used is Arial</sup></sub>

## Billboards

1. [Halloween 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halloween_III:_Season_of_the_Witch)
2. [Christine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christine_(1983_film))
3. [Assault on Precinct 13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assault_on_Precinct_13_%281976_film%29)
4. [The Fog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fog) (Stevie Wayne operated the radio channel KAB from a lighthouse)
5. [Dark Star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_Star_%28film%29)
6. The Coup de Villes, John Carpenter's own 80s hardrock band, most famous for their [soundtrack to *Big Trouble in Little China*](https://youtu.be/D03E9kUTTtQ) (ref. 11).
7. [Escape From New York](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_from_New_York)
8. [They Live](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/They_Live)
9. [The Thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Thing_%281982_film%29) (protagonist MacReady used to kill Things with a flamethrower)
10. [They Live](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/They_Live)
11. [Big Trouble in Little China](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Trouble_in_Little_China) ("Pork Chop Express" was the nickname of Jack Burton's truck)

## Characters

4) Alice Cooper's possessed bum character from [*Prince of Darkness*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince_of_Darkness_(film))
5) Jack Burton from [*Big Trouble in Little China*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Trouble_in_Little_China)
8) Napoleon Wilson from [*Assault on Precinct 13*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assault_on_Precinct_13_%281976_film%29)
9) Lt. Ethan Bishop from [*Assault on Precinct 13*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assault_on_Precinct_13_%281976_film%29)
19) MacReady from [*The Thing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Thing_%281982_film%29)
23) John Nada from [*They Live*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/They_Live)
24) Frank Armitage from [*They Live*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/They_Live)
36) Michael Myers from [*Halloween*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halloween_(1978_film))
38) Snake Plissken from [*Escape From New York*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_from_New_York)

Comment: **Helpful hints:  None of the female characters are from *The Thing*, because there were no females in that movie.  I'm sure Jamie Lee Curtis' character from *Halloween* is in there somewhere, and I would be surprised if Adrienne Barbeau wasn't as well (Carpenter was married to her)**

Comment: 2 Could be Starman, 15 Sutter Cane, 33 Laurie Strode, but I am not 100% sure, so I dont add them. Maybe somebody can confirm or disprove my guesses.

Comment: @kl78 I thought about Sutter Cane, too, but the grey hair doesn't really fit at all. Another possibility would be Father Malone.

Comment: I'm not even sure they *are* all movie characters. Many of them look so decidedly normal and indistinguishable that they could be pretty much everyone. And the supply of more distinct characters wasn't that short, from the Duke of New York, over Cabbie, to some guys from Street Thunder or Lo Pan. Most of them might really just be ordinary fillers. But it's hard to say.